# How to set a value present in anchor tag to a hidden field upon clicking on the hyperlink text(i.e. value present in anchor tag)?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, hyperlink, hidden-field

I'm haiving following code:

```
<a class="que_issue" href="#">
      QUE38552
</a>
```

Now I want to set the value **38552**(only question id and **not** the string **QUE**) to the following hidden field:

```
<input type="hidden" name="question_id" id="question_id" value=""/>
```

Also note that the page shouldn't be redirected to another location as I'm showing the pop-up dialog on the click of above hyperlink. The script to show the pop-up dialog is working fine, no issue with that. There are many such hyperlinks containing different question ids(like **QUE38552**) are present on the same page. I want to set the value of hidden field of only that question id on which user has clicked. This hidden field is present on the diaolg pop-up which I'm going to show. Can anyone plese help me in this regard? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Try,

```
$('.que_issue').click(function(e){
 e.preventDefault();
 $('#question_id').val($.trim($(this).text()).substring(3));
});
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/72Jyc/)

Comment: Sorry the ** are not present. I've modified my question. Can you please modify your answer accordingly?

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```
$('.que_issue').click(function() {
    var number = $(this).text().match(/[0-9]+/g);
    $('#question_id').val(number);
});
```

**[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ja6CG/1/)**